# Are any tools or techniques available to solve the "placement of safety points" problem?

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, operations-research

> **Definition 0.** Given a metric space $X$ and subsets $H$ and $S$ thereof, define: $$d(H,S) = \sup_{h \in H} \inf_{s \in S}d(h,s)$$

(This as an asymmetric version of the [Hausdorff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance).)

Here's some slightly dodgy intuition about why this definition is interesting: imagine that $S$ is a set of "safety points" and $H$ is the set of "homes where people live." If a disaster strikes and people begin making their way to the nearest safety point, then $d(H,S)$ (read: distance from houses to safety) describes the elapsed time until everyone gets to safety, assuming that everyone leaves immediately and moves with speed $1$.

I'm interested in the following problem: $H$ = "the homes where people live" is given, and we need to place $k$-many safety points in an optimal way, so that the elapsed time before everyone is safe is minimized. More formally:

> **Problem.** Given
>
> - $H$, a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and
> - $k$, a natural number
>
> find:
>
> - a subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying $|S| \leq k$, such that for all "competing" subsets $S'$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying $|S'| \leq k,$ we have $d(H,S) \leq d(H,S')$.
>
> **Question.** Have any tools or techniques been developed to solve this problem for sufficiently nice $H$?

Comment: Nice question! Your question, I think, is similar (but is not the same!) to the "optimal ball backing problem", where given a solid $H$ you are looking for the largest number $k$ of pairwise disjoint balls of fixed radius (say, $1/2$) contained in $H$. Given the set $S$ of centers of such collection of balls, we have that the balls $B(s,1), s\in S$, cover $H$ which implies that $d(H,S)\le 1$. I think both questions are equally hard and it makes sense for you to check the ball packing literature to see if some ideas are useful in your setting.

Comment: @studiosus, thanks for the tip. (And the kind words.)